# Change http status 503 to 200 when serving app_offline.htm for specific URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, app-offline.htm

The app_offline.htm file that ASP.NET serves returns the http status 503.  This is the correct behavior for most situations.  However, in the scenario where a specific URL is requested (e.g. https://www.mywebsite.com/monitor), I'd like to change the returned http status to 200, while still returning http status 503 in all other situations.  Is this possible?

The reason why I want to do this is whenever we do scheduled maintenance on our website, we use the app_offline.htm file, but we don't want our uptime monitoring service (Pingdom.com) to report downtime during our scheduled maintenance.

I assume this would have to be at the IIS level because the app_offline.htm gets served very early on in the request processing cycle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that `App_Offline` is only there to take the ASP.NET part down, it has nothing to do with the IIS site. All non-ASP.NET request -like .htm- will go through the normal IIS pipeline.

That being said, a `HTTP 503` is an unavailable service error. The `App_Offline.htm` take the site partially offline, it is normal and correct that all ASP.NET request get a `503` response when the site is offline.

Bypass this with a HttpModule or whatever code in the ASP.NET pipeline is not a valid solution.

Since you'are already creating/copying the `App_Offline.htm` in your IIS root during maintenance, I'll suggest to add `maintenance.htm` as a default document for your `/monitor` folder or your IIS site and create/copy a `maintenance.htm` file in it during maintenance : then the default page will be reach whatever the ASP.NET site is offline or not.

If your probe is calling the `http://servername/monitor/` uri without any page specified, it will work.

You just have to delete it -like you delete your `App_Offline`- after the maintenance.

Comment: JoeBilly, I thought that by checking your answer, you would have gotten the full bounty, but it looks like selecting your answer was not enough.  Because of this, your answer was auto-selected and you only got half the bounty.  Not sure what I did wrong, but sorry you didn't get the full bounty.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not a problem :) I don't chase bounty. For your information : if you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount (from the faq ;)).

Comment: Hmm, I'm still trying to convince myself that this doesn't look a lot like my (earlier) answer ...

Comment: You'r right oleschri. My feeling is my 3 first paragraphs were missing in your answer. IMHO, the .htm trick is more a workaround and the real answer is to say how App_Offline work : then the asker understand why the "trick" become the solution ;) Anyway, note that I voted up your answer as soon as I saw I suggested the same workaround ;)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the app_offline.htm logic is handled inside the ASP.NET 2.0 module but before any application loading begins (which is of course the idea behind app_offline.htm *g*).

I suggest:

- Add a virtual directory named `monitor` to the root of your (disabled) Website and assign it to some IIS-readable folder.
- Do not make the virtual directory an application, so ASP.NET should keep its hands off that folder.
- Put e.g. a copy of your `app_offline.htm` file renamed to `default.htm` (or whatever is in your default filename list) into that folder.

This way IIS should serve the html file with a 200 response when accessing `https://www.mywebsite.com/monitor`.

Ah, and to honor Adilson's warning about search engines, just add a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` to your file in case the website is reachable by search engines.

Comment: Very interesting.  How do I not make my virtual directory an application?  I tried this technique, but IIS is still serving the app_offline.htm file from the root.  I wasn't able to disassociate the virtual directory from being an application though.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, it works for me. Just tried it again to test. The `Application settings` in tab `Virtual Directory` and the settings in tab `ASP.NET` of the virtual directory should be grayed out. Is it that way in your settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IIS 7 and the integrated pipeline you can still create a HttpModule for requests that are not part of the ASP.NET pipeline, i/e .Htm requests.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis7-integrated-pipeline/

[ASP.NET IIS 7 lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Modules)

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/

Comment: This looks very promising.  I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Interesting :) Maybe difficult to combine with the App_Offline : App_Offline is managed (and redirected) by ASP.NET and my guess is IIS 7 integrated HttpModules may not be aware about the App_Offline behavior ? Anyway you can create your own Module and forget App_Offline. I just found this : http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/09/02/Take-an-ASPNET-Application-offline-with-HttpModules.aspx

Comment: Well, looking at the ASP.NET source (using reflector) it seems that there is no actual redirection, the HttpRuntime itself (before the HttpApplication is actually loaded) just writes the file to the response stream. looking into it some more, it seems that the runtime *still* raises the "OnPreSendRequestHeaders" and "OnPreSendRequestContent" events, So It's possible that you can still use those events. I haven't tested (I don't have IIS 7 installed here) but you should still check if BeginRequest and EndRequest fire as part of the integrated pipeline if you don't want to use the other events.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the Global.asax Application_Error method, identify your url, identify your error, redirect to your page

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim ctx = HttpContext.Current
        dim myerror = ctx.Error
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Path = "mypath" Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/mydestpage.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
```

This will return first 302 for your previous request, and then redirects to a page that shows 200...

Comment: Thanks Luke.  I don't think that will work because (according to ScottGu) Microsoft implemented the app_offline.htm logic very early in the request cycle and before your application is even loaded, so I don't believe any ASP.NET code will ever execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [http redirect](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect) at the IIS level.

Comment: Thanks Darin, but a redirect will return a 302 status code.  What I'd like to do is return 200.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man. Take care when doing this! A 200 response can do your error page be indexed by google and others search engines.

If you still choose to do so, I think you should create a HttpModule, and put it on the top of the module stack. This module must test if the App_offline.html file exists, if so, then you test if the request came from the Site Monitor. In this case you can response with a 200, otherwise, the response code must be 503 to avoid bad site indexing.

Important: your site application pool must be in Integrated Mode.

Comment: Thanks Adilson, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I created an HttpModule and subscribed to the BeginRequest event.  But it never executes if the app_offline.htm file exists.  I think the app_offline file is served very early and before ASP.NET code executes.  If you somehow got this to work, can you please share your code?  Thanks.

Comment: Uncheck the verify file exists in IIS